# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. My server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this issue is already on the forum, but my case is a bit special, I have a site that has two connection string in the web-config as follows:

```
<add name = "myConnString" 
     connectionString = "user id = user1, password = user1; Persist Security Info = False; Database = clarins_abs; Server = teck2012; Connect Timeout = 60; Trusted_Connection = False;" 
     providerName = "System.Data. SqlClient "/>

<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I put the site on my local iis server everything works fine, but when I put the site on another server I receive this error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   Establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found gold
>   Was Not available. Verify That the instance name is ok and That SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server / Instance Specified).

I have SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Can you connect to the Server using SSMS? If so, you know that the server is accepting remote connections. If not, look at the server and enable tcp/ip and enable port 1433 in the firewall to accept connections.

Comment: I can connect to my server using ssms, the problem is not here

Answer (score 1):

In your second string, the .\ indicates that the SQL server instance is located on the local machine. Your local iis server probably has this instance, while the other server does not.

Comment: Hi erix, what should I do to specify the instance on the other server ?

Comment: @wben first verify this is actually the issue by doing some logging the first time either connection is used. If this is the issue, you'll either want to point this connection string back to the instance on your local iis server, or create a copy of that DB on the server and then change the string to point to it

Comment: I think the problem comes from the second connection string, But I don't understand one thing,actually my database is on the folder where I have my site, I copied the entire folder on the other server so my database should exist on the server.

Comment: I mean my local database (ASPNETDB.MDF) is in my app_data folder

Comment: @wben ok. can you confirm that the running process on the server has access to that db?

Comment: I don't think so, But how to verify that ?

Comment: @wben connect to it via SSMS and check out the security settings. Since it's using integrated security, the preocess running the website will need permissions to access it

Comment: Ok let me explain: I have a web-site and within this web-site I have a lot of folders. As you know, with ASP.NET Configuration in Visual Studio 2010, I created roles(for security) and  I have specified each role in each folder, once the roles created, there is a database (ASP aspnetdb.mdf) which is automatically created on the App_Data folder, so I don't see the relation between this database and SSMS . (I'm really really confused)

Comment: I have faced some troubles with read-only flags on some SDF Files. I know it isn;t the case here, but is the write flag on you DB there???

Answer (score 0):

Type "SQL Server Configuration Manager" in start menu (win vista / win 7) and check that TCP/IP protocol is enabled.

Comment: Hi THX-1138 , TCP/IP IS Enabled

Answer (score 0):

We have to check following thing for this

1.Check Tcp/IP settings in sqlserver configuration manager settings.[If it is disable ,make sure we have to enable the status for TCP/IP](http://forums.asp.net/t/1827197.aspx/1?a%20network%20related%20or%20instance%20specific%20error%20occurred%20while%20establishing%20a%20connection%20to%20sql%20server)

2.Add port to fire wall exception at fire settings. Details for sql port:

Name : SQL

Port Number: 1433

Protocol: Select TCP